# How to check file type?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have code like this and I want to know what type of file I get. png or jpg. How to do this?

```
var image;
File _image;
image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
setState(() {
     _image = image;
});
```

Comment: just check the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only thought of this solution, intercepting the path string.

```
List<String> imagePathArr = _image.path.split(".");

print("image's type  =  ${imagePathArr[1]}");
```